# ActionBar background fill? How did Google do this?

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar

If you haven't seen already, the Google IO 2014 app has a unique feature. If you were to download it right now and open up any one of the sessions and scroll down slowly, you'd see that as soon as the colored bar reached the ActionBar, it stops scrolling and the ActionBar spacing (height) is filled with a color using an animation. I was wondering how Google accomplished this, any ideas?

(Download the app check what I mean, sorry was unable to make gif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google I/O](https://github.com/google/iosched) app is an open source project. Just download the code, read it and see how they do it ;)

if you are too lazy to read the source code XD here you have a detailed tutorial about how to get exactly that: [Pushing the ActionBar to the Next Level](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what @DiegoPalomar suggested is not the exact solution as we want an animation, not just fading. As far as I understood from the iosched sources, Google is dinamically changing a View's properties which is just an empty colored View behind the titles. But to my mind, the Google's implementation is a bit complicated.

You can check [FloatingTitleBar](https://github.com/Zandbee/FloatingTitleBar) sample code to catch the idea.